# Sorting in CTE expression

Tags: t-sql

I am retreiving all users from DB ordered by number of followers for each user DESC

```
 with TH_Users as
(
    SELECT [ID]
      ,[FullName]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[ImageName]
      ,dbo.GetUserFollowers(ID) AS Followers
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by ID ) AS 'RowNumber' 
from dbo.TH_Users
Where CultureID = @cultureID

)
Select ID,[FullName]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[ImageName], Followers from TH_Users
Where RowNumber BETWEEN @startIdx AND @endIdx
Order BY Followers DESC
```

I am using a function to get number of followers for each user. now is I user Followers column as the column order for ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by Followers ) AS 'RowNumber'

I get a compilation error.

Putting Order BY Followers DESC at the end of the query will not give the intended result.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `AS` to give an alias to a column, that alias is not available *within* the query - logically, applying aliases to columns is (almost) the very last part of evaluating a query.

So if you want your `ROW_NUMBER` with the CTE to be `OVER` what you alias as `Followers`, you must express it in the same terms as the column itself:

```
;with TH_Users as
(
    SELECT [ID]
      ,[FullName]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[ImageName]
      ,dbo.GetUserFollowers(ID) AS Followers
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by dbo.GetUserFollowers(ID) ) AS 'RowNumber' 
from dbo.TH_Users
Where CultureID = @cultureID
)
```

Note that this will *not* cause the function to be evaluated any more times than it is currently.

*(I have not tested this)*